# Interfacing with virtual hosts within a PHP / Symfony2 application

Tags: php, apache, symfony, virtualhost

I have a Symfony2 PHP application where each user has their own subdomain. At the moment this is just running as the default Apache host with no virtual hosts. When someone accesses their subdomain, it obviously calls the main application which looks just like its own installation within a virtual host.

Now, the application is evolving and some users want additional functionality, including running their own domain aliases and installing SSL certificates on those aliases. I'm also starting to think more the security of each user's subdomain within the system. I think the logical step forward is to give each user their own virtual host. Ultimately, these virtual hosts should have read access to the main application, read/write access to their own folder for uploads and limited system resources. I'm looking at CloudLinux to solve the last problem.

I'm flexible with regard to which web server to run, as long as it performs well and is relatively secure. Can anyone point me in the right direction to create a setup that allows PHP to create and redact virtual hosts automatically within the web server and create/redact SSL certificates and domain aliases?

This isn't a question of a specific piece of code, but rather a question of the best overall approach to take.

Comment: This question violates stackoverflow's rules and is a mix 'recommend a tool' and belonging on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com). i couldn't resist and answered with a few considerations though :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's an option I have considered and will look into further. It'll be interesting to see what other answers I get, if it stays open.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what kind of application you're talking about but as you mention SSL certificates i assume there is **sensible data** involved.

This is a tough question and it strongly depends on what rights you want to grant to your customers (i.e. running their own scripts/bundles or even SSH access) or how sensible their data is.

A complete guide is not what stackoverflow is for and there exist too many ways and tools to tackle this situation.

**Your best bet is to give all your clients their own (v)servers.**

With the use of provisioning tools like chef or puppet among a few other little helpers and the right workflow ... you will have these servers set up in no time and be able to maintain them almost as comfortably as a single server.

You could even create new server instances on the fly.

Even if all your clients run the same application and have web access only there's always a high security risk when running them all on the same server.

Basically if the application has one real security issue - there is a high probability that all of your client's will be affected and can easily be exploited. (It doesn't take much to determine all domains running on the same IP address either)

As long as you don't have distinct users for each application and an own PHP (parent) process/pool (i.e. `php-fpm`) for each of them ... it will be easy to gain access to the other application's configuration,files,database (,...).

session-information, temporary upload directories (,...) are easily exposed between these applications ...

Especially with opcode cache (i.e. Zend Opcache or APC) or user cache (i.e. APCu) in place there will be possible interference between these applications and serious security issues can quickly appear due to the fact that the PHP (parent) process has access i.e. to the caches of all the other applications.

In the context of symfony2 i'm talking about i.e. container-configuration cache or doctrine query-caches being exposed.

MySQL aside (no possibility to have things like separated slow-query logfiles for different databases with a single process for each application) you will need a lot of RAM for these processes with a growing number of customers and there are **countless things to consider**.

You could start off by

- creating users for each application ...
- creating jailshells for all of them
- add jailshell'd php pools for every single one of them
- restrict the rights of your webserver to a minimum
- ...

using i.e. php-fpm the webserver only needs access to the public assets and not a single php file.

The webserver will be proxying requests to the php process that itself only needs read access for most of the files and write-access to upload-folder, session-save-path, log-folders, cache-dirs (,...) ).

I'm not saying that it's impossible to achieve ... but it's not an easy task and you should really know what you're doing.

Do yourself a favor:

As we're talking about a symfony2 application - where professional developers/freelancers typically charge 80$/hour and more ... charge your customers the few $/month for their own (cloud) server instance!